# how to connect to Microsoft bot framework from mvc web application

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, botframework

I created a simple mvc web application sends a message in JSON format.

which URL should i enter in my app that connects the bot?

and how does that bot receive message and send back the response?

As of now I am using bot emulator by Microsoft and my bot app working fine.

DO i need to publish my bot app on azure???

Comment: "which URL should i enter in my app that connects the bot?" <-- please post the relevant code.  "and how does that bot receive message and send back the response?" <-- That is a very broad and general question.  Is there something specific you are trying to do that requires more detailed knowledge of how the BotFramework receives messages and sends responses?  "DO i need to publish my bot app on azure?"  The bot needs to be hosted somewhere. Also: what channels are you planning to use for your bot?

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EricDahlvang . I am new to this Bot Framework so i have many questions about it. I dont have any idea how it works.

Comment: This is the place to ask.  However, questions on StackOverflow are usually code related and more specific.  Nonetheless, I've attempted to answer the questions you've posted here.  If the answers aren't clear, please let me know and I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which URL should i enter in my app that connects the bot?

Using the **WebChat control** is probably the easiest way to get your bot on the internet.  You can use the following url in an iframe on any webpage by default (after your bot is created, published, and configured in dev.botframework.com):

`<iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YOUR_BOT_ID?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE"></iframe>`

Note: you should call https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens with your secret, and get back a server to server token, replacing s with t, so you don't expose your bot's secret. This is all explained here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/embed-chat-control2/

> and how does that bot receive message and send back the response?

Messages are sent and received in json format.  There's quite a bit of documentation and examples online. Like this: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html on **Sending and Receiving Activities**

> As of now I am using bot emulator by Microsoft and my bot app working
>   fine.
>
> DO i need to publish my bot app on azure???

Your bot will need to be published somewhere. Azure is the best place to host a bot right now because of Microsoft's dedication to the framework and its future.

There's also the **security aspects and complexities**, explained by Dan Driscoll here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1006#issuecomment-244087904:

> Bots are just web services. If you unhook security and talk directly
>   to the bot's activity endpoint, you can operate your bot locally on
>   your machine. It may be simpler to just open your own API on the bot's
>   service because emulating what we do in the channels is actually a
>   fair amount of work. (It's by no means impossible -- this is exactly
>   what we do in the emulator -- but there is a fair amount of complexity
>   there.)
>
> If you want to stay within the Bot Framework universe, the bot's
>   endpoint does need to be accessible by the Bot Framework services,
>   i.e. on the internet. If you're publishing on the internet, you will
>   probably want to secure your endpoint, and the Bot Framework security
>   model by design does not allow just anyone to call a bot -- our
>   libraries only allow in authentic Bot Framework services.